# extracting index from a 2D array Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-indexing

I have an image (named `gray_image`) of shape `(1830, 1830)`. After some image processing (I have created superpixels) I got a 2D array named `segments` (of shape `(1830, 1830)`), which contains values from 0 to 72.

I need to take the index from where I find the value "0" in `segments` and use that index to save the value from `gray_image` in a new array (named: `arr`).

I think an example will help you understand my problem better:

Let's say I have this image, an 2D array with 3x3 dimension:

```
gray_image = numpy.array([[1, 1, 1],
                          [2, 2, 2],
                          [3, 3, 3]])
```

And this is my segments array, an 2D array with 3x3 dimension :

```
segments = numpy.zeros([[0, 0, 1],
                        [0, 1, 2],
                        [1, 2, 2]])
```

I need to create an algorithm that outputs the array `arr` with shape `(3, 3)`.

```
 arr = np.array([[1, 1, 2]  # on the first line are the values from gray_image that correspond with value 0 from segments
                 [1, 2, 3]  # on the second line are the values from gray_image that correspond with value 1 from segments
                 [2, 3, 3]]) # on the third line are the values from gray_image that correspond with value 2 from segments
```

I just realized that the count of numbers from each segment are different, so I'm not sure if this is possible with and 2D array. I'm thinking of using a collection such as a dictionary to save all the information related to the index.

So, here is what I did so far:

```
i = 0
j = 0
k = 0
n = 0
m = 0
arr = np.empty([1830, 1830]) # empty array
for k in range(0, 72):
     for i in range(0,1829):
         for j in range(0,1829):                      
             if segments[i][j] == k:
                 arr[m][n] = gray_image[i][j]
                 n = n + 1
             if i == 1829 and j == 1829:
                 m = m + 1
```

But this isn't working at all, I've got this error:

```
arr[m][n] = gary_image[i][j]

IndexError: index 1830 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1830
```

I'm kinda stuck on this for a few days so any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the number of elements for each segment always the same? This is important because numpy does not do ragged arrays.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks for the question, I just realized that the numbers from each segment are different. I need to rethink how should I do this. Maybe I should use a dictionary instead of an array.

Comment: I'll post an answer for both situations.

Comment: Please add commas to the array samples, so they're valid python code. If they are arrays, make that clear in code as well.

Comment: I edited your array definitions to show you what I had in mind. Just `np.array` and some commas is all it really takes. Thanks for staying responsive.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Yes, the answer is working for me, I am still trying to understand it better but I got all the help I needed! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's assume that your labels array is conducive to making a numpy array to begin with, i.e., that number of elements per label `N` is constant and number of labels `M` x `N` is the same as the image size. If that is not the case, you can't construct a 2D numpy array as the result.

The trick is to identify the regions. For this, we will use [`np.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
idxa = np.argsort(segments, axis=None).reshape(m, n)
arr = gray_image.ravel()[idxa]
```

If your labels are not conducive to an array output, the result above still useful. Instead of reshaping `idx` to the correct output shape, leave it as-is and figure out split indices to make a list of arrays:

```
idxl = np.argsort(segments, axis=None)
splits = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(segments.ravel()[idxl])) + 1
lst = np.split(gray_image.ravel()[idxl], splits)
```

The label corresponding to each segment does not have to be zero-based or in any way special, so you may want to get the values as an array of the same length as `arr`/`lst`:

```
labels = segments.ravel()[idxa[:, 0]]  # For arr-based solution
labels = segments.ravel()[idxl[np.r_[0, splits]]] # For lst-based solution
```

You can trivially turn the result into a dictionary by zipping `labels` and either `arr` or `lst`:

```
dct = dict(zip(labels, lst))  # Works with arr too
```